# Delphi 7 почему по разному работает на разных компах с MS Word?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ms-word, автоматизация, ole

В общем пишу пограммку с автоматизацией с Word'oм. Проблема в том что команда SaveAs('адрес') на одном компе работает правильно(сохраняет по команде), а на другом открывается окно "сохранить как". Причём если сохранить вручную пишет, что "ошибка команды"

Не могу понять в чём может быть причины, ведь я использую на обоих одну и ту же версию Word 2007 года.  Винда... получается на 10 не работает сейчас, но и раньше не работала на 7... Поэтому, думаю это не из-за неё.

Люди добрые, помогите разобраться в чём причина и как это можно исправить....

Comment: Что значит "работает нормально"?

Comment: правильно(сохраняет по команде)

Comment: Команда SaveAs - это аналог почти одноимённого пункта главнго меню "Save as ...", что в русской локализации выглядит "Сохранить как ...", что вызывает диалог сохранения файла для возможности изменения его имени и пути сохранения. Так понятнее?

Comment: Тогда почему на одном компе он сохраняет самостоятельно, а на другом открывает диалоговое окно? Причём в команде прописывается путь, значит она должна самостоятельно сохранять файл без дополнительных окон...

Comment: Как вы используете Word? Через OleVariant или через TWordApplication? И в догонку - указанный в SaveAs путь к файлу точно существует?

Comment: DisplayAlerts := false попробуйте

Comment: Метод не поддерживается

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй метод [SaveAs2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-saveas2-method-word). Метод, добавленный немного позднее и возможностей у него больше.

Comment: НЕ работет     прописал MsWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(' ');                                
 пишет method 'SaveAs2' not supported by automation object

Comment: наверное он появился в 2010... тогда это не вариант в твоём случае

Comment: Может там надо поиграться с параметрами при вызове SaveAs? Там точно нет подавления появления диалогового окна параметрами? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas.aspx

Comment: В делфи там вроде только адрес и имя сохраняемого файла прописываются...

Comment: В общем... нужен человек, кторый совсем недавно работал с delphi 7 по теме автоматизации с Word'ом.... тот кто хотя бы мог попасть в такую передрягу...

Comment: А лучше обновить всё это старое дерьмо. 10 лет назад выпущена твоя версия ворда, и больше 10 версия Делфи.

Comment: у меня задача стоит, чтобы работать 2007 версией офиса...

Comment: Это понятно, но если задача будет стоять, чтобы работало на офис 97, под виндовс 12, выполнить будет ещё сложнее. Не всё можно и нужно предусматривать в своей программе.